# Typescript validator not working in my angular IDE Eclipse Plugin

Tags: angularjs, typescript, eclipse-plugin, editor

If i enter wrong code in typescript editor it doesn't show me any compile time error. I don't know why typescript validator doesn't work. I am using eclipse Neon.3 Release (4.6.3) with angular IDE plugin. Do i have to add anything further to support typescript validator please let me know.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure which errors are not being flagged for you but there is a setting in the project properties (TypeScript preference page) for enabling TSlint validation if tslint.json is present in the project. This is a per-project setting, not available for the workspace as a whole.

If this doesn't help, perhaps you could give an example of the type of error that is not being flagged? Or is it that the errors aren't being flagged but do appear in the Markers or Problems view? Try a fresh workspace and a new Angular project (or other project with Typescript files) just to check if this may be some corruption in your existing workspace settings.